# XML, XSD and XSLT student's project

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have to make xml, xml schema and xslt for my university project. I'm getting 3 errors from validator. Can you help me?
Thats my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xslt"?> 
<mojehobby>
        <naglowek>
            <naglowek_glowny>
                Moje hobby
            </naglowek_glowny>

            <podnaglowek>
                muzyka 
            </podnaglowek>
        </naglowek>
        <images>
            <zdjecie src="AP4.jpg" href="https://www.facebook.com/AfterPeppers/"></zdjecie>
            <zdjecie src="COSTER1.jpg" href="https://www.facebook.com/Coster-433619970040235/"></zdjecie>
            <zdjecie src="TSF2.jpg" href="https://www.facebook.com/The-Second-Floor-200535016957502/"></zdjecie>                
        </images>
        <dana>
            <artykul>
                <tytul>
                    Historia
                </tytul>
                <naglowek_artykulu>
                    O muzyce i nauce
                </naglowek_artykulu>
                <tresc_artykulu>     
                <tresc>
                  Some text
                </tresc>
                </tresc_artykulu>
            </artykul>
        </dana>
        <o_artykule>
            <autor>
            <imie_autora>Krzysztof</imie_autora>
            <nazwisko_autora>Stencel</nazwisko_autora>
            </autor>
            <data>15.12.2019</data>
        </o_artykule>
        <stopka href="">
        <tresc></tresc>
        <data></data>
        </stopka>
</mojehobby>
```

Thats XSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="krotki_string">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="article">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="400"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>    

<xs:simpleType name="imie">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="nazwisko">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="data">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="tresc">

</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="image">
    <xs:attribute name="src"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="href"/>
</xs:complexType>   

<xs:complexType name="images">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="zdjecie" type="image" maxOccurs="3"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>   

<xs:complexType name="tresc_artykulu">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tresc" type="article" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="footer">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tresc" type="krotki_string"/>
        <xs:element name="data" type="data"/>
    </xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="o_artykule">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="autor" type="simpleType">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="imie_autora" type="imie"/>
                        <xs:element name="nazwisko_autora" type="nazwisko"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="data" type="data"/>
        </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="naglowek">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="naglowek_glowny" type="krotki_string"/>
            <xs:element name="podnaglowek" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>   

<xs:element name="dana">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:complexType name="artykul">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="tytul" type="krotki_string"/>
                <xs:element name="naglowek_artykulu" type="krotki_string"/>             
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="tresc_artykulu">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="tresc" type="article" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>   
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="mojehobby">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="naglowek"/>
        <xs:element name="images" type="images"/>
        <xs:element ref="dana"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>   
</xs:element>

<xs:attribute name="href"/>
</xs:schema>
```

And there are errors:

```
Validation  87, 15  s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'dana' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: sequence.
 Validation     64, 47  src-element.3: Element 'autor' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element.
 Validation     40, 15  cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'o_artykule'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the errors:

1. The error

   > Validation 87, 15 s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'dana' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: sequence.

   was emitted, because you forgot to wrap the xs:sequence in an xs:complexType. You did it right in the following xs:element `mojehobby`.
2. Next, also in `dana`, you tried to define an xs:complexTypes in a sequence - that's not allowed. Merging all elements in an xs:sequence will fix it.
3. The error

   > Validation 64, 47 src-element.3: Element 'autor' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element.

   simply refers to fact that you try to apply two types to the same element. Get rid of one and you'll be fine. (Here: the `type` attribute)
4. The error

   > Validation 40, 15 cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'o_artykule'. No child element is expected at this point.

   does occur, because you forgot to include an xs:element as a child of the `mojehobby` rule. This also applies to `stopka` and its children.

I also added some hints to the XSD file. It still throws errors, because the content is invalid: the content of several nodes exceeds the xs:maxLength restrictions defined in the string types.
However, here is the debugged, working version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="krotki_string">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="article">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="400"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>


    <xs:simpleType name="imie">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="nazwisko">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="data">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="tresc">

    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="image">
        <xs:attribute name="src"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="href"/>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="images">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="zdjecie" type="image" maxOccurs="3"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="tresc_artykulu">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tresc" type="article" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="footer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tresc" type="krotki_string"/>
            <xs:element name="data" type="data"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="href"/>
        <!-- Note that attribute definitions have to appear at the end of the complex type - here referencing the attribute at the end of the file -->
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="o_artykule">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="autor">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="imie_autora" type="imie"/>
                            <xs:element name="nazwisko_autora" type="nazwisko"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="data" type="data"/>
            </xs:sequence>            
        </xs:complexType>        
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="naglowek">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="naglowek_glowny" type="krotki_string"/>
                <xs:element name="podnaglowek" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="dana">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="artykul">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="tytul" type="krotki_string"/>
                            <xs:element name="naglowek_artykulu" type="krotki_string"/>

                            <xs:element name="tresc_artykulu" type="tresc_artykulu" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>        
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="mojehobby">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="naglowek"/>
                <xs:element name="images" type="images"/>
                <xs:element ref="dana"/>
                <xs:element ref="o_artykule"/>            <!-- Added element for reference type -->
                <xs:element name="stopka" type="footer"/> <!-- Added element for defined type -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>        
    </xs:element>

    <xs:attribute name="href"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Hope this helps.